# Foreman DNS proxy does not set records

Tags: foreman

I am building a foreman puppet infrastructure in my test lab, all setup components were installed through puppet (modules: forman-puppet, foreman-forman, forman-foreman_proxy, foreman-dns).

Everything except the dns proxy is working fine for me, but i can't get it to work at all and have no idea anymore.

This is how my configuration looks like.

```
dns.yml:
:enabled: https
:use_provider: dns_nsupdate
:dns_ttl: 86400

dns_nsupdate.yml:
:dns_key: /etc/bind/rndc.key
:dns_server: 127.0.0.1
```

Foreman is showing DNS just fine under Smart Proxy Services. All necessary links to the DNS Smart Proxy are set too, so I configured my domain and subnet and pointed them to my configured Smart Proxy.

The strange thing is that when I turn on DEBUG mode and create new hosts I dont see anything DNS related in the logs, there are no errors, warnings or infos. It seems that I am missing something here.

I would appreciate any poke in the right direction :)

Thanks in advance
Best Regards